# How to save complete webpage using google puppeteer?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

Is there any way using google puppeteer to control chromium to save the complete webpage? (Manually, I right click some empty space on the page, select "Save as..." in context menu, and then save the page as type "Webpage, Complete")